# How to make an MSIX (or standalone executable) for installing a keyboard layout

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer, msix, keyboard-layout, msklc

I've been trying to make an MSIX which would install a keyboard layout on Windows. I have a folder exported from MSKLC which contains a few dlls, 3 msi files (ia64, i386 and amd64) and a setup (exe) file. Running the exe or any of the 3 msi's installs the keyboard just fine. I'd like to upload the keyboard layout to the Microsoft store - which requires an MSIX or standalone msi file.

I've already tried apps like MSIX packaging tool and Advanced Installer to try repackaging the files into MSIX, but the keyboard doesn't show up even after the MSIX installs successfully. My guess is that maybe they are unable to capture system actions for adding keyboard layouts.

Are there any other ways to combine the files into an MSIX, or to create a standalone msi which would include the required dlls in it (instead of requiring paths to the dlls)?

Thanks